# Difficulty changing max_allowed_packet in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to change the `max_allowed_packet=20M`. This is that I've done:

```
$ mysql -u root -e 'show variables like "max%"'

+----------------------------+----------------------+
| Variable_name              | Value                |
+----------------------------+----------------------+
| max_allowed_packet         | 16777216             |

$ sudo vim /etc/my.cnf

# my.cnf
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=20M

$ sudo service mysql restart

$ mysql -u root -e 'show variables like "max%"'

+----------------------------+----------------------+
| Variable_name              | Value                |
+----------------------------+----------------------+
| max_allowed_packet         | 16777216             |
```

Why is nothing changing here? What do I need to do to actually change this setting? (Note that I am using ec2 here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
[mysqld]
max-allowed-packet=20M
```

instead.

Computer can be *SO* picky!

Answer (score 0):

Your restart query is incorrect. It should be:

$ sudo service mysqld restart

You missed "d" in mysqld